# Half-Rendered update window

Tags: 21.04, 21.10

I did an update from ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10 on my raspberry pi 4b and halfway through it, I closed the update window (Big mistake). When I tried to update it later,  the update window resembles a wierd, unreadable, barely-rendered smudge. What could have wrong? Here it is. (It is a miracle that I could take this screenshot with all thae glitches and all.)

[image]

That's the software updater window now. What is up with it? It seems to be doing the install because every now and again, windows pop up asking me for approval for things or to choose stuff.

Comment: there is no "upgrade"  from 21.04 to 20.10. Please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly. How was the supposed "upgrade" achieved? What commands did you use?

Comment: Oops. typo. It was from 21.04 to 21.10 Thanks. I used the non-commandline software updater.

Comment: If you closed the window that I *think* you are describing, it's bad. Real bad. Time to reinstall.

Comment: You're right. It barely works. Is it possible to reinstall without having to flash an entire new image on to the sd card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked over a bunch of the system files. They all were called "corrupted" files when I looked at the properties.  I had to reinstall; it was the only fix.